# Configure Zabbix API through Nginx the most performant way

Tags: nginx, zabbix

I'm looking for a complete performant solution to configure Zabbix through Nginx, not Apache HTTPD that comes by default. I personally dislike HTTPD and interesting if there any specific recommendation for Zabbix? Is default configuration for Zabbix API polling with PHP+FPM enough?

Currently what happens when we use Zabbix API through Apache, stalled time is totally unacceptable, first 5-10 requests are fine, each subsequent happens slower and slower.

[image]

[image]

BTW Nginx/HTTPD comparison shows a huge difference, see Nginx below

[image]

Comment: Have you read https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/high_availability_Zabbix_Frontend ? Main focus is on the usage of Pagespeed, but underlying that is zabbix+nginx.

Comment: @fvu right, I will try that straight away, is there any Nginx/Zabbix specific pitfalls?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, there are plenty references to installations running Zabbix on nginx on the [Zabbix forum](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/). By the way, adding pagespeed is a good idea, it really helps.

Comment: @fvu pagespeed is good but we use Zabbix API mostly so the performance hit we see with Apache is slow connection time during batch of API requests

Comment: Are you sure Apache is the bottleneck there? I'd be very interested to hear about your findings, as our experience with zabbix performance issues were nearly exclusively db related, the biggest step to solve these was to switch to a partitioned database (running a 52.39 nvps system with around 5000 items and 2000 triggers).

Comment: Ok that stalled figure is quite telling :)

Comment: Good question! Let me double check the mysql slow log and other stuff!